# Codeigniter-oauth2-server integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, codeigniter-3

I want to integrate Oauth2 with Codeigniter. For that I found this project:

https://github.com/grasses/codeigniter-oauth2-server

But unfortunately, the readme file doesn't provide the clear information about usage.

What should be the URLs to get the token? What should be the parameters?

If somebody has used some other libraries then I'm comfortable with switching.

PS: I want to use Resource owner Password Credentials grant type

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to use authentication library in codeigniter. I usually use **ion_auth** , it works fine. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

and it also provides documentation. If you are still confused you can reply to this post. Hope It helps

Comment: I want to use Oauth2 for API authentication. Can I use this library for that?

Comment: Yes, you can use ion_auth library for api authentication as well

Comment: Unless your API uses your website sessions for authentication, then no, you can't use Ion Auth for your API.

Answer (score 0):

Ion Auth is an authentication library, but is NOT the same as oAuth.  Since API's don't have sessions, Ion Auth won't provide the necessary feature for you, unless you build your own methods of tokenization into the user table.  I'm actually trying to find a solution to the same problem.  Also, from the Ion Auth website, they also state that if your looking for API authentication, then you can try https://auth0.com/